# Necessidade de declarar variáveis em uma função em Javascript

Tags: javascript, funções, return

Olá. Estou começando a aprender lógica de programação. 
Quando vou criar uma função em Javascript, declaro e peço para retornar seu valor.

```
     function exemplo(teste){
              var saida = teste + 4;
              return saida;
     }
```

Bem, quando vou usar a função, estou declarando novamente a saída.

```
var teste = parseInt(prompt('Diga um número.'));          
var saida = exemplo(teste);
alert(saida);
```

Se eu peço para retornar o valor de *saida*, por que tenho que declarar a variável de novo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não precisa declarar ela de novo. Bastaria retornar a soma direto no `return`:

```
function exemplo(teste){
  return teste + 4;
}
```

Isso tem a ver com o [escopo das variáveis](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp). Quando você declara `var saida` dentro da função, essa `saida` terá escopo local, ficará restrita dentro da função por causa do `var`.

Por outro lado, o `var saida` fora da função, tem escopo global, poderá ser usada em qualquer parte do código. Ou, caso você omita o `var` em `saida` dentro da função, ela passa a ter escopo global.

Por exemplo:

```
function exemplo(teste){
  soma = teste + 4;
  return soma;
}

var teste = parseInt(prompt('Diga um número.'));          
var saida = exemplo(teste);
alert(saida + "/" + soma);
```

No código acima serão criadas 2 variáveis globais: `saida` e `soma`, com os mesmos valores.

Outro exemplo:

```
function exemplo(teste){
  var soma = teste + 4;
  return soma;
}

var teste = parseInt(prompt('Diga um número.'));          
var saida = exemplo(teste);
alert(saida + "/" + soma);
```

Neste código acima dará erro, pois a variável `soma` não existe fora da função, porque foi declarada dentro dela com `var`.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção. Irei pesquisar mais sobre.

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa declarar novamente. Você pode fazer isso:

```
alert(exemplo(teste))
```

Porém, se você precisar usar esse resultado em mais de um lugar, nesse caso é indicado guardar o retorno na variável. Dessa forma, você não precisará chamar o método novamente toda vez que esse valor for necessário.

O fato de poder não quer dizer que é mais indicado. Mesmo só utilizando esse retorno uma vez, você pode optar por guardar o retorno na variável para que o código fique mais limpo.

Essa forma:

```
var saida = exemplo(teste);
alert(saida);
```

É mais legível que dessa forma:

```
alert(exemplo(teste))
```

Do mesmo modo, você poderia fazer isso:

```
alert(exemplo(parseInt(prompt('Diga um número.'))))
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. Estou estudando especificamente antes de dar continuidade no curso. Valeu!